# Using Ternary Operator with strings in C

Tags: c, c-strings, conditional-operator

Trying to use ternary operator to assign string to `remarks` variable based on the average grade. But `remark` doesn't get assigned properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int grade1, grade2, grade3;
    double average;
    char remarks[15];

    printf("Enter Grades of each subjects: \nEnglish: ");
    scanf("%d", &grade1);
    printf("Mathematics: ");
    scanf("%d", &grade2);
    printf("Programming: ");
    scanf("%d", &grade3);

    average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;

    remarks[15] = (average > 74) ? "Passed":"Failed";
    printf("\nAverage grade: %.2lf %s", average, remarks);
```

The program intends to get the average of 3 numbers(grade) and then either declare pass or fail depending on the result.

The program gets the input correctly however the only thing that's getting printed out is the average.

When I modify the code and write it like this, it works just fine.

```
printf("\nAverage grade: %.2lf %s", average, average > 74 ? "Passed" : "Failed");
```

I think the issue is with re-assigning the variable remarks after getting all the grades.

EDIT: Added the placeholder %s in the first `printf` statement.

Comment: Arrays are not assignable. To copy a string literal to a char array, use strcpy(). Do insure that the target array is big enough to hold the result (which it is in this case).

Comment: This has nothing to do with ternary operator but about how to use arrays and how to copy strings. Start by writing `remarks[15] = "Passed";` and then figure out why that line doesn't make the slightest sense from there.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```cpp
  const char* remarks;
  remarks = (average > 74) ? "Passed":"Failed";
  printf("\nAverage grade: %.2lf", average, remarks);
```

or

```cpp
char remarks[15];
strcpy( remarks, (average>74) ? "Passed" : "Failed" );
printf( "\nAverage grade: %.2lf", average, remarks);
```

They are different.
In the first case `remarks` is a pointer, in the second case `remarks` is a char array.

If you are wondering what is the difference between combinations of char pointers and const, look at this write up.

Note **this is C++ specific** as C allows some of these:

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/rz6bh4qzP

Writable pointer to a writable location

```cpp
char* a1;     // ok
char* a2 = nullptr; // ok
char* a3 = "Hello"; // error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' 
a1 = nullptr; // ok
a1 = "Hello"; // error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' 
a1[0] = 'x';  // ok
```

Writable pointer to a const location

```cpp
const char* b1; // ok
const char* b2 = nullptr;   // ok
const char* b3 = "Hello";   // ok
b1 = nullptr; // ok
b1 = "Hello"; // ok
b1[0] = 'x';  // error: assignment of read-only location
```

Const pointer to a writable location

```cpp
char * const c1; // error: uninitialized const
char * const c2 = nullptr;  // ok
char * const c3 = "Hello";  // error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'
c1 = nullptr;    // error: assignment of read-only variable
c1 = "Hello";    // error: assignment of read-only variable
c1[0] = 'x';     // ok
```

Const pointer to a const location

```cpp
const char * const f1;      // error: uninitialized 'const f1'
const char * const f2 = nullptr; // ok
const char * const f3 = "Hello"; // ok
f1 = nullptr; // error: assignment of read-only variable
f1 = "Hello"; // error: assignment of read-only variable
f1[0] = 'x';  // error: assignment of read-only location
```

Comment: The question was never tagged C++. This was a good answer until the point where you suddenly switch language to C++ and start a long, off-topic lecture about C++-specific features. One subtle difference between C and C++ is for example that C allows a `const` without assigning a value to it. Basically this makes C suitable for various hardware-related programming, unlike C++. Similarly,  `nullptr` only exists in C++. `char* a3 = "Hello";` is fine (though stupid) in C, unlike C++ where it isn't allowed. And so on. I would rollback your last edit since it's all incorrect/off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a `const char *` to a `char` (`remarks[15]`). And that index is out of bounds, as C array indexing starts at `0` and for a 15 element array goes to `14`.

Use instead the following, which simply stores the remarks as a pointer to the correct string literal (`const char *`).

```
char *remarks = (average > 74) ? "Passed" : "Failed";
```

Comment: `const char *remarks` would be better.

Comment: Interpreting the code as C, as opposed to C++, the OP is in fact assigning a `char *` (not a `const char *`) to a `char`.  For historical reasons, the fact that attempts to modify string literals produce UB is not connected to the data type of string literals.  That's also why your suggested change will probably not elicit a compiler warning, even though `const char *remarks` would be a better choice in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

- You're attempting to assign a string to a single array element, `remarks[15]`, instead of the entire array.  Furthermore, since arrays in C are zero-based, the array indices range from `0` to `14` - attempting to write to `remarks[15]` will write to memory outside of the array.
- You cannot use `=` to assign array contents, strings or otherwise.  You must use the `strcpy` library function<sup>1</sup>, like `strcpy( remarks, average > 74 ? "Passed" : "Failed" )`.  Or you'll have to assign individual array elements:

  ```
  remarks[0] = average > 74 ? 'P' : 'F';
  remarks[1] = 'a';
  remarks[2] = average > 74 ? 's' : 'i';
  remarks[3] = average > 74 ? 's' : 'l';
  remarks[4] = 'e';
  remarks[5] = 'd';
  remarks[6] = 0;  // terminate the string
  ```

---

1. Or `strncpy`, or `memcpy`, or similar.